# Response.BinaryWrite DIV

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to write PDF to a div from DataBase i.e. Retrieve a Byte[] from Database and Reponse.BinaryWrite to a div.

We do similar thing for Images using src = "anotherpage.aspx" where image is written on anotherpage.

Is it possible with PDF without using IFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is show a PDF file inside a DIV, you're going down the wrong path. You either need to:

- Convert the PDF to Flash (ala [Flash Paper](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashpaper/))

or

- Convert the PDF to HTML (like [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/) does using HTML 5).

Then you can embed the PDF inside a DIV. But no browser I know of supports directly embedding PDFs.

Otherwise you have to put the PDF in an IFRAME, but how this is shown is PDF plug-in dependent.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The reason it works with a `src=otherpage.aspx` request is that the src attribute results in the user's web browser making a completely separate request for the other resource.  You're serving up an additional page to make that happen.  Writing a PDF file directly is trying to inject the PDF into the same request as your page - not really "similar" to your img src at all.  In fact, what is most similar to the "src=otherpage.aspx"  method is the iframe approach that you mentioned.

As a side note, you our "AnotherPage.aspx" example should really be changed to "AnotherPage.ashx".  Note the letter 'h' in there.  That means you're using a handler rather than a page, which will perform better.

Comment: Thank for the input Joel and for ashx tip.